# MongoDB as datasource to Flink

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-flink

Can **MongoDB** be used as a *datasource* to **Apache Flink** for processing the Streaming Data?

What is the *native implementation of Apache Flink* to use *No-SQL Database* as data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Flink does not have a dedicated connector to read from MongoDB. What you can do is the following:

- Use `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createInput` and provide a Hadoop input format for MongoDB using Flink's wrapper input format
- Implement your own MongoDB source via implementing `SourceFunction`/`ParallelSourceFunction`

The former should give you at-least-once processing guarantees since the MongoDB collection is completely re-read in case of a recovery. Depending on the functionality of the MongoDB client, you might be able to implement exactly-once processing guarantees with the latter approach.